# How to change the date format in a DB aware combo box?

Tags: delphi, combobox, delphi-7, date-format, datefield

I'm using `TwwDbLookupComboDlg` component. I want to change the date format in the combobox (as shown below) from `1/1/2009` to `Jan 2009`, any idea?

[image: TwwDbLookupComboDlg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the TDateField's DisplayFormat :

```
with Table1 do
    TDateField(FieldByName('Date1')).DisplayFormat:='mmm yyyy';
```

Comment: if it still display '1/1/2009', what does "i can change the combobox date format with your code" mean ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a dataware control, you can format the field data using the [`DisplayFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDateTimeField.DisplayFormat) property.

```
TDateTimeField(ADODataSet1.FieldByName('START_DATE')).DisplayFormat:='mmm-yyyy';
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with this component but I think when you're filling up the combo, for each field in the list you can use shortmonthnames

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=ShortMonthNames